# Is there any example to show how does the JVM parameter UnsyncloadClass work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parameters, jvm

I am new to Java, I learned that there is a setting for JVM "UnsyncloadClass", I googled it here

http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html

```
"UnsyncloadClass    Unstable: VM calls loadClass unsynchronized. Custom classloader must call VM synchronized for findClass & defineClass   false   bool"
```

So I am not sure what does this mean,  is there any code to illustrate how it works? 
  BTW, is this stable in Java7 or Java8 ?
  From literal meaning, I thought this might enable the JVM load classes in an async way, am I right? 
  It will be great if any code illustrated how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this option is ON, `loadClass` method does acquire a ClassLoader lock, no matter if this ClassLoader is registered as [parallel capable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/cl-mt.html) or not.

This option is never going to be "stable" nor recommended for production, since its behavior obviously violates the [ClassLoader API specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).